# Importing/Exporting Google Contacts in Java App

Tags: java

I'm developing a Java Application (A phone-book in fact) and I need a java library to import/export my google account's contacts in the application. Is there any library which makes it easier than the [APIs google has introduced in its website](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/g2=KEbOAv1hNhrJSavlJedTuQ)? 
Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two popular libraries are:

- [Google OAuth2 API Libraries for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/oauth2/v1): focused on Google OAuth2 APIs;
- [Apache Oitu](http://oltu.apache.org/): OAuth/OAuth2 protocol implementation in Java. It also covers others "OAuth family" related implementations such as JWT, JWS and OpenID Connect.

Both have Maven support.

Another possible solution is to use broad address book services like [CloudSponge.com](https://cloudsponge.com/contact-importers/gmail), which offers a [Java API](http://www.cloudsponge.com/integrations/java) and support for other popular sources, in case you're planning beyond just Gmail.